# Infinite recursion of constexpr template function

Tags: c++, templates, generics, constants, constexpr

I implemented the FNV-1A function in C++ with constexpr functions, but I ran into a strange problem.

This version works without a problem:

```
template<size_t N>
static constexpr uint32_t fnv1a_internal(const char (&data)[N], size_t position, uint32_t state) {
    return position >= N - 1 ? state : fnv1a_internal(data, position + 1, (state ^ data[position]) * 16777619UL);
}

template<size_t N>
static constexpr uint32_t fnv1a(const char (&data)[N]) {
    return fnv1a_internal(data, 0, 2166136261UL);
}
```

But when I make position a const generic argument, like this

```
template<size_t N, size_t Position>
static constexpr uint32_t fnv1a_internal(const char (&data)[N], uint32_t state) {
    return Position >= N - 1 ? state : fnv1a_internal<N, Position + 1>(data, (state ^ data[Position]) * 16777619UL);
}

template<size_t N>
static constexpr uint32_t fnv1a(const char (&data)[N]) {
    return fnv1a_internal<N, 0>(data, 2166136261UL);
}
```

it will, upon instantiation, fail to compile with the compiler complaining about the function exceeding a recursion limit.

The functions is intended to be used with string literals like this:

```
uint32_t hash = fnv1a("Hello world");
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Please add the instantiation which blows its mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ternary operation doesn't avoid template instantiation.

So when `Position >= N - 1`, you still instantiate `fnv1a_internal<N, Position + 1>` which instantiates `fnv1a_internal<N, Position + 2>` and so on.

Since C++17, you might use `if constexpr`:

```
template<size_t N, size_t Position>
static constexpr uint32_t fnv1a_internal(const char (&data)[N], uint32_t state) {
    if constexpr (Position >= N - 1) {
        return state;
    } else {
        return fnv1a_internal<N, Position + 1>(data, (state ^ data[Position]) * 16777619UL);
    }
}
```